# Meta tags for allowing JavaScripts to run in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I have created my own Chrome Extension called Frogga. You can call it from

https://fivy.org/irc/page1.json

[Frogga at GitHub](https://github.com/irondocks/frogga)

I've tried everything. But all I get is the first layer of JSON. I've got it so that it will run deeper, but that's without the extension. I'd like to really raise the bar on coding sites, but it'll take a bit at this rate.

I tried adding a meta tag which clashes with everything in the dang the Irondocks pattern. Not being able to handle the situation is a problem. I'll have to figure something out with that. But yes, I've been looking for the meta content that will allow me to add listeners. I'm pretty sure I'm going to need actual Chrome API. Which is me rolling a rock up a hill at the point. So, please if anyone can help it's graciously appreciated.

```json
{
    "header": {
        "title": "Frogga",
        "css": "styles.css",
        "js": "http://localhost/irc/pipes.js;pipes.js"
    },
    "body": {
        "tagname": "body",
        "test": {
            "tagname": "select",
            "id": "tester",
            "options": "key:value;key2:val2",
            "style": "width:200;"
        },
        "table": {
            "tagname": "table",
            "style": "width:800px;height:600px;border:3px solid black;cell-spacing: 5px;",
            "tr0": {
                "tagname": "tr",
                "td0": {
                    "tagname": "td",
                    "id": "sample",
                    "textContent": "Click me!",
                    "style": "vertical-align:bottom",
                    "class": "yellow",
                    "x-toggle": "sample:yellow;sample2:green;sample2:orange;"
                },
                "td1": {
                    "tagname": "td",
                    "textContent": "",
                    "class": "orange"
                }
            },
            "tr1": {
                "tagname": "tr",
                "td0": {
                    "id": "sample2",
                    "tagname": "td",
                    "class": "green",
                    "textContent": ""
                },
                "td1": {
                    "tagname": "td",
                    "textContent": "",
                    "class": "red"
                }
            },
            "tr2": {
                "tagname": "tr",
                "td0": {
                    "tagname": "td",
                    "tdv": {
                        "modal": "j.json"
                    },
                    "class": "green"
                },
                "td1": {
                    "tagname": "td",
                    "textContent": "",
                    "class": "blue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go with Cursor (Great AI help). It now works perfectly.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Frogga",
  "description": "A Chrome Extension that loads irondocks.js and handles .irc files",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src http://127.0.0.1:* http://localhost:*;",
    "script-src": ["'self'"]
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*.irc", "https://*/*.irc", "http://*/*.json", "https://*/*.json"],
      "js": ["./pipes.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```